# ASP.NET Web API 2 -> Windows Authentication -> Impersonate Windows user on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, windows-authentication

We are developing an application with `Windows Authentication` that is used internally at a company. We have looked at `ADFS` but at the moment this is not an option. The problem is our test servers are entirely cloud based on `Azure`. I have been trying to find a way to activate a user but have not found a good solution.

My first idea was to turn off `authentication` completely. This works good but we have some resources that checks for user roles so I had to abandon that idea.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

Example method that returns `401 Unauthorized` with `authentication mode="None"`, obviously:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("TestMethod")]
public IHttpActionResult TestMethod()
{
    return Ok("It works!");
}
```

My second thought was to edit the `WebApiConfig` and try to add authentication headers in every request server side. However when I started looking at the `NTLM Authentication Scheme for HTTP` and the 4-way handshake I realized this would probably be impossible.

[NTLM Authentication Scheme for HTTP](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Other code for WebAPI registerations here
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());  
    }
}

class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Add authentication to every request...
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Since there is no `Owin (Katana)` I can not edit the standard App_Start -> Startup.Auth.cs -> `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` and try something there. I don't know how I would build up the "user object" anyway.

Is there anything we can do about this or do we have to test everything locally? If we could impersonate one user to be logged in for every request this would be fine in the test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @ste-fu for pointing me in the right direction. Complete code:

```
public class AppSettingsDynamicRolesAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AppSettingsDynamicRolesAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roleKeys)
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>(roleKeys.Length);

        foreach (var roleKey in roleKeys)
        {
            roles.Add(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[roleKey]);
        }

        this.Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsTestEnvironment"]))
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity("Spoofed-Oscar"),
                new string[] { WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Role.Administrator] });
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}

public static class Role
{
    public const string Administrator = "Administrator";
    public const string OtherRole = "OtherRole";
}
```

Can then be used like this:

```
[AppSettingsDynamicRolesAuthorize(Role.Administrator, Role.OtherRole)]
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{

    var userName = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;

    var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

    return Ok("It works!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of faking the authentication and authorisation you should be able to set a generic user principal with the appropriate roles using a FilterAttribute.

```
public class TestIdentityFilter :  FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity(),
            new string [] {"Administrator"});
    }
}
```

You will need to set `<authentication mode="None" />` as you did previously otherwise this code will never be hit in your test environment.

Adding this as a Global filter will override any other existing authentication system (for example if you deploy it to an authenticated environment by mistake). Obviously you will need to be very careful about only using this in your test system.

This example is based on MVC, I think there are some very small differences with WebApi but the basic principal applies.

Comment: thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. Posted an answer myself with working code.